# Count the Dtrec_ID in the databae

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, ajax

I just want to ask on how to count the Dtrec_ID, example to count how many 1 in there and it will display in the "Days Present" textbox.

[click this, to see the form.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHNpH.png)

[click this, to see the database.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVbaA.png)

Comment: not much we can do without code really

Comment: ok2, I will put it. but it is too long. isn't ok?

Comment: how about using a `where` clause

Comment: can you show it to me? @Dew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the query should look like this :

```
SELECT COUNT(Dtrec_ID) as DaysPresent FROM dailytimerec where Dtrec_ID=1 ;
```